# Rearrange modifier keywords in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

Is there any way to automatically rearrange modifier keywords in IntelliJ?

For example, if I have the following code:

```
private final static int x = 0;
final private static int y = 0;
static final private int z = 0;
```

Rearrange it to:

```
private final static int x = 0;
private final static int y = 0;
private final static int z = 0;
```

Comment: I guess a few `Find in Files...` is the other option. But, yes - this would be a nice feature.

Comment: The JLS canonical order for the modifiers above is private static final, not private final static. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to *Settings* and enable the *Editor | Inspections | Java | Code style issues | Missorted modifiers* inspection. It has a quick fix to sort the modifiers. This inspection is also part of *Analyze | Code Cleanup...*, so another solution would be to invoke that on your code.

Answer (score 3):

I had once looked up a similar formatting need. Explored "rearrange", "templates(command+shift+M)" etc, but this did not help. There is an "Arrangement" option under `Editor->Code Style->Java->Arrangement` tab. It looks like a rule editor, but that also did not help. To my understanding it is for ordering(sorting) members with in a class rather than ordering key words. It would have been really robust to have this feature under Reformat/Rearrange.

Anyway, only way I could come up with was to use Find|Replace with "regular expressions"
So, in the example you have given, we can **use find/replace**(⌘R in OS X) **with regular expression** as:

Find : `private final static|final private static|static final private`

Replace: `private static final`

Not very smart, but useful.
We can use combination of private/public if this needs to be applied to both  private and public. Also, it can be applied at package/path level. Example screenshot below

[image: Search Replace panel]